# PHP reply-to error - comes up with random email not sender of contact form

Tags: php, html, forms, email

I have a contact form set up on my website (done through Adobe Muse)
the email is set up to send to multiple address

One of those addresses has an auto confirmation bounce back email.
The From address is NOT the email entered in the form itself but the email associated to my Adobe I.D meaning I'm receiving ALL the bounce back emails and to others it looks like the forms are coming from a single email address not the people sending off the form on the website.

I've managed to track down the php code for the form itself but have very limited knowledge when it comes to coding. 
How can I get the code to make the "from" address or the repyl-to address the same as the person filling out the forms

See below

```
<?php 
/*  
If you see this text in your browser, PHP is not configured correctly on this hosting provider. 
Contact your hosting provider regarding PHP configuration for your site.

PHP file generated by Adobe Muse CC 2015.2.1.352
*/

require_once('form_process.php');

$form = array(
    'subject' => 'SSUPPORT FOR EXTENSIONS TO AVOCA BEACH PICTURE THEATRE IN LAND & ENVIRONMENT COURT - DA42661/2012 Submission',
    'heading' => 'New Form Submission',
    'success_redirect' => '',
    'resources' => array(
        'checkbox_checked' => 'Selected',
        'checkbox_unchecked' => 'Unselected',
        'submitted_from' => 'Form submitted from website: %s',
        'submitted_by' => 'Visitor IP address: %s',
        'too_many_submissions' => 'Too many recent submissions from this IP',
        'failed_to_send_email' => 'Failed to send email',
        'invalid_reCAPTCHA_private_key' => 'Invalid reCAPTCHA private key.',
        'invalid_field_type' => 'Unknown field type \'%s\'.',
        'invalid_form_config' => 'Field \'%s\' has an invalid configuration.',
        'unknown_method' => 'Unknown server request method'
    ),
    'email' => array(
        'from' => 'saveaseat@avocabeachpicturetheatre.com.au',
        'to' => 'saveaseat@avocabeachpicturetheatre.com.au,ask@centralcoast.nsw.gov.au,Carolyn.Wesley@gosford.nsw.gov.au,Ariella.Whitelum@gosford.nsw.gov.au'
    ),
    'fields' => array(
        'custom_U262562' => array(
            'order' => 1,
            'type' => 'string',
            'label' => 'Name',
            'required' => true,
            'errors' => array(
                'required' => 'Field \'Name\' is required.'
            )
        ),
        'Email' => array(
            'order' => 2,
            'type' => 'email',
            'label' => 'Email',
            'required' => true,
            'errors' => array(
                'required' => 'Field \'Email\' is required.',
                'format' => 'Field \'Email\' has an invalid email address.'
            )
        ),
        'custom_U262553' => array(
            'order' => 4,
            'type' => 'string',
            'label' => 'Message',
            'required' => false,
            'errors' => array(
            )
        ),
        'custom_U262696' => array(
            'order' => 3,
            'type' => 'string',
            'label' => 'Postcode',
            'required' => false,
            'errors' => array(
            )
        )
    )
);

process_form($form);
?>
```

Comment: Is this what you're looking for: https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1409392

Answer (score 0):

Or maybe if you add `replay-to` in `email array`, like:

```
'email' => array(
    'from' => 'saveaseat@avocabeachpicturetheatre.com.au',
    'to' => 'saveaseat@avocabeachpicturetheatre.com.au,ask@centralcoast.nsw.gov.au,Carolyn.Wesley@gosford.nsw.gov.au,Ariella.Whitelum@gosford.nsw.gov.au',
    'replay-to' => 'Email for replay'
),
```

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not hosting the website through Business Catalyst - If I were this would be easier (I think)

The code change didn't seem to work when changing/ resending the form
Is there anything I can add that'll replace the 'from' => with the email address of the the person filling in the form?